# Django admin site for limited privilege users

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django application, and have two apps within the project: accounts and store. In my store app, I have Product, Category model and other models.

I have admin site, from where I can register Products. In the accounts, I allow general people to signup and log in.

Now, I also want users to be able to register Products, so that they can sell their own products. However, I do not want to give them to a complete access to the admin site.

How can I give such limited access to the admin site to general users?

Thanks.

Comment: The admin is not meant to replace your own site; there's a reason the flag controlling admin login is called **is_staff**.

Comment: yOU CAN SET PERMISSIONS FOR USERS IN THE ADMIN ITSELF BY LOGGING AS SUPER USER

Comment: Don't do this. Take the time to build a frontend for your users. The admin is not and never will be meant for general user actions.

Comment: Why all the negative votes. Maybe hacking the django admin site is not an appropriate (or, at least, ideal) solution for this particular problem, but it is still a valid question...

Answer (score 1):

In admin you can make groups and assign access to models you wanted and same could be applied to users but you might be interested in limited access to models records to which logged user have itself added. in order to achieve this you have to define one column in model to foreign key to users like below I have defined model for company and assigned each company to user:

class Company(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
kam = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='KAM', blank=True, null=True)
address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
phone  = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
fax  = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)


class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Companies'
    #unique_together = (('name', 'kam'),).

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Now your model will be associated with user, Now you could restrict records to be loaded according to logged user using admin.py in modeladmin definition like given below:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(CompanyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    # If super-user, show all comments
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(kam=request.user)
```

thats simple let me know if this is what you want?

Also you could assign read only right. in model admin

Answer (score 1):

Admin uses a class `ModelAdmin` to render the page as you would probably already know. That class has a `queryset` method which you override based with a new filter, based on who is accessing the site, as suggested by sharafjaffri.

But that filtering alone isn't sufficient. You also need to filter the values displayed in the dropdowns, to only those created by the user. And then when saved, you should associate the new object with the portal of the user adding it.

Here is my quick untested implementation of the same:

```
class PortalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ('portal',)

    def queryset(self, request):
        """
        Filter the objects displayed in the change_list to only
        display those for the currently signed in user.
        """
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            return qs.filter(portal=request.user.profile.portal) 

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        the_model = db_field.related.parent_model

        if hasattr(the_model,'portal'):
            kwargs['queryset'] = the_model.objects.filter(portal=request.portal)
        return super(PortalAdmin,self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.portal = request.portal
        obj.save()
```